# How do you list the files in your home directory in RCloud (http://rcloud.social)?

Tags: r, rcloud

I uploaded a file in RCloud (http://rcloud.social) using the File Upload GUI in the right panel. It was successfully uploaded since if I try to upload it again by clicking on the blue upload button I get the message: "File blahblah.txt exists. OVERWRITE".

How do I see what files are listed in my home directory?

I tried `ls` in a shell cell and `list.files(R.home())` in an R shell.

Answer (score 2):

The question asks two different questions - uploaded file are stored in the `rcloud.upload.path()` directory, so you would list files in that path using

`list.files(rcloud.upload.path())`

The second question was about the home directory (which is not directly related to upload!). That is also ambiguous since the unix user directory may or may not coincide with the RCloud home directory - that depends on the deployment (e.g. whether each RCloud user maps to an actual unix user or not). The RCloud home can be queried using `rcloud.home()` while unix home would be simply `"~"`. Also note that `rcloud.home()` can be used to query other user's home as well (see documentation).

Finally, both `rcloud.home()` and `rcloud.upload.path()` can be used as path constructors, so if you uploaded file "foo.txt" you can access it using `rcloud.upload.path("foo.txt")`.

Answer (score 1):

RCloud uses a different home directory from command-line R, so you need to use

```
list.files(rcloud.home())
```

in an R cell.